# Alfred Workflow to move multiple files to Dropbox Folder

Tags: applescript, alfred

I am very new to AppleScript. I frequently share files from my local computer to Dropbox folder.

For example:

```
From: ~/Work/hello.txt
To: ~/Dropbox/zzz_ShareMe/hello.txt

cp ~/Work/hello.txt ~/Dropbox/zzz_ShareMe/ # or, just copy files from finder
```

I googled about AppleScript and came up with a workflow that copies ONLY ONE Item, But how can we select multiple files and copy them to Dropbox with an assigned hotkey (ctrl-alt-d)?

The contents of **Run NSAppleScript** is given below:

```
# Note: we should have ~/Dropbox/zzz_ShareMe folder
#
on alfred_script(q)
tell application "Finder"
    set source to (POSIX path of (the selection as alias))
    do shell script "cp -r" & space & quoted form of POSIX path of source & space & "~/Dropbox/zzz_ShareMe"

end tell
end alfred_script
```

I have shared my preliminary [workflow here](https://github.com/bhishanpdl/Shared/blob/master/Alfred-workflows/zz%20Copy%20To%20Dropbox.alfredworkflow.zip).

This workflow works for a single file.
If I select a file in Finder, ctrl-alt-d copies the file to `~/Dropbox/zzz_ShareMe/`, however, If I selected multiple files and used that hotkeys **nothing is copied**.

How can we fix that problem.

Help will be appreciated.

Related links:

http://www.packal.org/workflow/move
http://www.packal.org/workflow/copymove
https://www.alfredforum.com/topic/4195-move-selected-finder-item/

**Update**
I tried another script, but it still fails.

Required task:

1. select multiple files in Finder
2. ctrl-alt-d
3. it should copy all files to `~/Dropbox/zzz_ShareMe/`.

The new script is given below:

```
on alfred_script(q) 

tell application "Finder"

set source to selection

end tell

if (count of source) is greater than 1 then

set fileList to every item of source

repeat with source in fileList

doMove(source, q)

end repeat

else

doMove(source, q)

end if

end alfred_script

on doMove(source, destination)

set source to (POSIX path of (the source as alias))

set destination to "~/Dropbox/zzz_ShareMe"


do shell script "cp -r" & space & quoted form of POSIX path of source & space & POSIX path of destination

end doMove
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally, you should have posted this question to the [Alfred Forum](https://www.alfredforum.com/).  However, your problem is quite a simple one, so I'm happy to lend a hand here.

Essentially, your AppleScript for the single-file workflow inherently self-limits to processing a single file because the variable `source` is coerced into an `alias`, which is a unary data type (a single value).  There is a class called `alias list`, which—as the name implies—is suitable for a list of aliases.

You've also mixed AppleScript with Bash script, which can be very useful in other situations, but is just a bit weird here since there's no reason to do so.  So, I'll give you separate AppleScript and Bash solutions.

### The Workflow

Create a workflow that compromises the following *hotkey trigger* connected to the **Run Script** (*not* **Run NSAppleScript**) action (see the [Alfred Help pages](https://www.alfredapp.com/help/) for more information about these two actions, but generally speaking, you'll never need to use the **Run NSAppleScript** action):

[image: Alfred Workflow]

Double-click on the *hotkey trigger* to configure it.  In the first tab (*Hotkey Settings*), I presume you know how to set the desired hotkey.  However, also set the *Argument* field to *Selection in macOS*.

In the second tab (*Related Apps*), you can limit the action of the hotkey so that it operates only when *Finder* has focus.  Drag *Finder*'s app icon into the list box to do this (the easiest way is to trigger *Alfred*'s search field, type in *"Finder"*, and drag the icon from here to there).

Save the settings.

### The Script

Double-click the **Run Script** action to bring up the editor pane.  You can select the desired language in the first drop-down list: the two we're interested in for the purposes of this question are ***`/bin/bash`*** (or your equivalent list entry) and ***`/usr/bin/osascript (AS)`*** (or equivalent).

`osascript` is the engine that compiles and executes AppleScripts.

`AS` refers to AppleScript; `JS` refers to JavaScript.

#### Bash

If you elect to use Bash, select **with input as argv**.  Delete any sample code that appears in the editing field, and enter this code:

```
cp "$@" ~/Dropbox/zzz_ShareMe
```

#### AppleScript

If you choose AppleScript, the input type doesn't matter here.  Delete any sample code that appears in the editing field, and enter this code:

```
tell application "Finder" to reveal ¬
    (duplicate (selection as alias list) ¬
    to folder "zzz_ShareMe" ¬
    of folder "Dropbox" ¬
    of home)
```